# Is it possible to include minute and seconds data in a time series apex chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

I am trying to also input the time in seconds along with the date range, how can I do that inside of series? Here is my current code, only showing the date range in days.

```
series: [
 {
  name: 'Dataset One',
  data: [ 
   {
    x: 'Dataset One',
    y: [
     new Date('2020-01-30').getTime(),
     new Date('2020-02-20').getTime()
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How about adding the hours and minutes before considering adding the seconds? You are entering datea without hours, minutes, and seconds

Comment: How do I add the hours and minutes?

Comment: `new Date('2020-01-30T00:00:00');`  ---  **00:00:00** is `hh:mm:ss` --  And is in 24 hour format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost all the way there ...  You just need to add the `time` to your `Date`.  You can also refer to the [Date Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) on MDN docs.

```
new Date('2020-01-30T00:00:00').getTime(),
new Date('2020-02-20T00:00:00').getTime()
```

The `T` is in 24 hour format .. `hh:mm:ss`